# asp.net wrong password just logs me in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i have a simple website with asp.net membership authentication, so some reason which ever password i type for any user just logs me in. Whether i type fffffffff or 55555555 as the password for any user, am just loggedin.

The wasn't behaving this way just 1 day back. Any ideas what could be wrong, or where i should start troubleshooting from?

Comment: the website is just still on developer machine, its not a live site.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758462/old-password-still-working-after-password-change-in-asp-net-membership. @Katu - ask the question once.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

in your Web.config and not:

`<allow users="*"/>` or `<allow users="?"/>`

to ensure that you're not allowing anonymous access.

Answer (score 1):

check the webconfig as see if you have the code to prevent anonymous users loggin in and to redirect them....